# knockout losing model when pressing button for the second time

Tags: .net, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Got an old project in .net that needs few new features. We have a major problem with knockout somehow when pressing button for the first time everything works as it should, but when it is pressed for the second time it goes kaput.
Error

```
GeneratedCode.ts:5564 Uncaught TypeError: source.accountNumber is not a function
    at _Mapper.unwrapPnsBankReportListItem (GeneratedCode.ts:5564)
    at Function._Mapper.convert (GeneratedCode.ts:4673)
    at Function._Mapper.unwrapDlgBankReportViewModel (GeneratedCode.ts:4714)
    at DlgBankReport.OnClickSearchButton (DlgBankReport.ts:102)
    at Object.eval (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout-3.1.0.debug.js:2437), <anonymous>:3:101)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (knockout-3.1.0.debug.js:3108)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.0.js:4371)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-2.1.0.js:4057)
```

cshtml button

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block click-by-enter btn-primary" 
                    data-bind="click: function (data, event) { $root._Dialog.OnClickSearchButton($root, function (r) { $root._mapViewModel(r); }); }">Meklēt</button>
        </div>
```

ts

```
public OnClickSearchButton(modelObservable: Pns.Models.ViewModels.DlgBankReportViewModelObservable, success: (r: Pns.Models.ViewModels.DlgBankReportViewModel) => any): void {
            var focusElem = $(':focus');
            Pns.Instance.showPleaseWaitDlg();
            const obs = Pns.Models.ViewModels._Mapper.unwrapDlgBankReportViewModel(modelObservable);
            DynamicLocator.CreateProxy("Pns.Business.Dialogs.DlgBankReport", null, (<any>window).PnsInstance._connection, function (dlg: Pns.Business.Dialogs.DlgBankReport) {
                $.ajax(Pns.Configuration.ApiRootUri + "AccountReport/rpc/ExecuteCreation", {
                    data: JSON.stringify(obs),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (modelResult: Pns.Models.ViewModels.DlgBankReportViewModel) {

                    },
                    error: function () {

                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

it breaks down at this line in ts with said error.

```
const obs = Pns.Models.ViewModels._Mapper.unwrapDlgBankReportViewModel(modelObservable);
```

Have no clue why it doesnt work, as everywhere else it works as it should work. If anyone has idea why and how to fix it please let me know. Models are generated so there are no mistakes in them.
Error happens inside list with other model. Its mapping is also code generated and works elsewhere, this is the only place where it breaks down.

Comment: The error is saying that `modelObservable` should have an observable named `accountNumber`.  An observable is a function.  Hope this helps you.  :-)

Comment: Yes, it have it when button is pressed for the first time, but when its pressed for the second time, I get following error. Have no idea why or how we get this error only in one place where everything else work as it should work. @JoseLuis

Comment: Perhaps `$root._mapViewModel(r)` deletes this field.  I can't help, I'm sorry.